# fluentd doesn't tag the events properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, elasticsearch, fluent, fluentd

I have a simple fluentd configuration:

```
<source>
  type forward
</source>

<source>
  type tail
  path /var/log/nginx/access.log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/nignx-access.log
  tag nginx.access
  format nginx
</source>

<source>
  type tail
  path /var/log/nginx/error.log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/nginx-error.log
  tag nginx.error
  format nginx
</source>
```

And then I have the appropriate `<match>` tag after the sources. These logs are being shipped to an ElasticSearch instance on AWS. The problem is that, they show up but without a tag. So the nginx access log shows up properly but with not 'nginx.access' tag. This causes problems because now there's no way to categorize the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @repeatedly on fluentd's slack:

include this in the match tag :

```
<match my.logs>
  @type elasticsearch
  include_tag_key true
  tag_key _key
</match>
```